# Select prevent change on keypressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some business logic on `'#mySelect'` change. When I click on select or press any button matching option, this option is instanly selected (not highlighted as default). So I need to keep default hightlighting logic and keep my business login in onChange. By my own I achieved only separating events:

```
$('#mySelect').on('change keyup keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.type !== 'change' && event.which !== 13) {
        $(this).find(':selected').trigger('hover');          
        return false;
    }
    ...// onChange logic
})
```

But for now matching option is not hightlighted and onChange successfully executing when I press return button or click.
Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: If you're internal logic is segregated by event type, why are you forcing all the events to run though that same logic?  It would make more sense to split the event handlers up and have them conditionally call other methods for common logic between them.

Comment: when I split events I have to return false from callback anyway, which disables default options highlighting

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can not use events on `<option>` tag cross browser. Whatever you are trying to do with `hover` will not be supported in some browsers...notably IE. That's one reason why `<select>` replacement scripts are popular

Comment: so, I can't separate events when button is pressed and option is hovered and event when selecting is actually finished?

Comment: No you can only use events available on the select itself like `change`. Definitely `click` is a bad one on select since it fires on open and on selection with no way to differentiate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in not elegant way:

```
var keyNotPressed = true;
if (event.type !== 'change' && event.which !== 13) {
   keyNotPressed = false;
}
if (event.type === 'change' && !keyNotPressed) {
....
}
```